# Update Ubuntu under Parallels desktop

Tags: apt, parallels, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to update my Ubuntu 20.04.2 ARM64 bits running using parallels using the common :
`sudo apt update` and I'm getting the following error :

```
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Ign:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:4 https://download.ni.com/ni-linux-desktop/stream/deb/ni/focal focal InRelease [3,064 B]
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Ign:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease Ign:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease Err:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate. Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification.
[ІР: 52.222.169.60 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Release file for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 85d 3h 8min 50s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for https://download.ni.com/ni-linux-desktop/stream/deb/ni/focal/dists/focal/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 62d Oh 4min 595). Updates for this reposi
tory will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 85d 3h 9min 585). Updates for this repository will not
be applied.
E: Release file for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 85d 3h 8min 55). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Could you help me with this issue please ?

Comment: I am not sure about this one. Do you have Ubuntu Live Patch installed, activated and running?  That is how I update my Ubuntu 22.04 VM (non ARM)

Comment: Ubuntu Live Patch installed is installed but not activated. It needs a suscription that I don't have

Comment: You need to go to Ubuntu and activate your user ID and password to use Live Patch. I had to do that. It did not cost anything for a couple of Ubuntu Guests.